# Editing plot.default() with trace() does not change the function

Tags: r, plot, trace, traceback

I am debugging a script from a package I need for an analysis. The package uses `plot()` to plot the output of the bayesian hierarchical model. One of the plots takes a data frame of the elements that did not converge as the input for `plot.default()`. The issue I have is that if everything converges, the data frame is empty (`NULL`), but the plot function still expects an input.

The error message reads:

```
Warnung: no non-missing arguments to min; returning InfWarnung: no non-missing arguments to max; returning -InfWarnung: no non-missing arguments to min; returning InfWarnung: no non-missing arguments to max; returning -InfError in plot.window(...) : endliche 'xlim' Werte nötig
```

I tried to solve the issue by editing the plot.default() function with `trace("plot.default", edit=TRUE, where = plot)`. I added the following statement:

```
  function (x, y = NULL, type = "p", xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL,
  log = "", main = NULL, sub = NULL, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL,
  ann = par("ann"), axes = TRUE, frame.plot = axes, panel.first = NULL,
  panel.last = NULL, asp = NA, xgap.axis = NA, ygap.axis = NA,
  ...)
{

if(!is.null(x)){

(...)

}else{
    print("NULL")
  }

}
```

If I just run the `plot.default()` function the change works as intended. But when I run the model output through `plot()` I get the same error message. `traceback()` tells me that the issue is again the `plot.default()` function:

```
4: plot.window(...)
3: localWindow(xlim, ylim, log, asp, ...)
2: plot.default(out_check_model_bh_intra_location$MCMC_conv_not_ok)
1: plot(out_check_model_bh_intra_location$MCMC_conv_not_ok)
```

Why does the edit not work when I don't run the function separately?

Comment: You can actually define a `plot.NULL` method `plot.NULL <- function(...) invisible(NULL)`. Does that solve things?

Comment: I found another solution by redefining the `plot.default` function. I am not sure if your solution would also work (or how it would have to be implemented), as it will still call `plot.default` when I run the `plot()` function on my model output.

Comment: No, if you pass `NULL` to `plot` it would call `plot.NULL`, not `plot.default`. The code in my comment above _is_ the implementation. In my view, this is a safer approach than redefining `plot.default`

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch to S3 methods is made quicker by caching copies of them.  I guess `trace` only modified the original copy, not the one in the cache.

You can see the cache; it's the environment named `.__S3MethodsTable__.`.  Run `ls(.__S3MethodsTable__.)` to see what is being kept there.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have been the issue. I managed to work around it by defining a function with the edited script and assigning it to `plot.default` instead of using `trace()`.